# Display picture in MVC from SQL Server 2012 database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I've been trying too display image from my application MS SQL Server in MVC by creating an Custom Html Helper.

Code of the CustomHtmlHelper below:

```
public static class CustomHtmlHelper
{
    public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string alt)
    {

        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
        tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));
        tb.Attributes.Add("alt", alt);

        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

Code of the Details view below:

```
@Html.Image(@Model.Photo,@Model.FirstName)
```

Code of Namespace configuration in WebConfig.cs file

```
<add namespace="SchooLinkPx_DEV.Controllers.CustomHtmlHelper"/>
```

Comment: Did you check your HTML source to see what is being rendered?

Comment: Which Web.config did you add the namspace? in the project or view folder?

Comment: Web Config.cs in the Views Folder

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way can slove it.

**One**

You need to add your extension method namespace on *Views/Web.config*

Add nodes as follows this.

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="SchooLinkPx_DEV.Controllers.CustomHtmlHelper"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

After you already namespace on view's config you need to **reopen** the project I think you will see the extension method on the view.

*Note:* remember to **reopen** project when you add the namespace on webconfig, Because reopen will reload your new addition namespace

**Two**

Add the namespace on the top of view.

```
@using SchooLinkPx_DEV.Controllers.CustomHtmlHelper
```